# Exclude records by values on other records with the same value

Tags: sql-server

My Table looks like this:

```
ID  type

12  1 
13  2
12  1
14  1
15  1
15  2
16  1
14  3
```

The ID might repeat.
I need to Take all IDs which have type 1 but don't have another record with type <> 1
So the result will be:

```
12
16
```

What would be the right approach?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest an `EXISTS` or `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation might be the simplest approach:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(type) = MAX(type) AND MIN(type) = 1;
```

We could also try a self join approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND
       t2.type <> 1
WHERE
    t1.type = 1 AND
    t2.ID IS NULL;
```

### Demo

The demo is for the second self join query, but you may plug the first query into the same demo to try that as well.

Comment: Thanks. The first method won't work because the types are not really 1 and 2 and it will require calculations, but the second seem to work.

Comment: @Hana Well the first could certainly be made to work, e.g., using a subquery to first compute the types, and then aggregating using my query.  But glad that the second is already working for you.